# Node.js: Parsing a json-ld / JSON with "@"-symbol

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, fs

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
{"marker":[{"@attributes":{"start":"Im Berge",
"finish":"Eichelberger Stra\u00dfe"
...
```

I am trying to parse the attributes inside the "@attributes", but have not found a way to do it. What I tried so far:

```
const fs = require('fs');  
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('route1.json', 'utf8'));  
console.log(jsonObj['@attributes']);
```

Also tried the same with

```
console.log(jsonObj.marker['@attributes']);
```

Neither of which work. I understand that this is supposed to be a json-ld and that I'm supposed to parse an object with an "@" sign with ['@attributes'], but either way I always get an error or undefined. I got the JSON from an API I wanna use and it is in there multiple times, so I have no way around it.

Comment: marker is an array of object , you have to access it in the following way `console.log(jsonObj.marke[0]['@attributes']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.marker` is an `array` so:

```
console.log(jsonObj.marker[0]['@attributes']);
```

But you may want to loop through it:

```
jsonObj.marker.forEach(marker => console.log(marker['@attributes']));
```

---

You can `require` a JSON file, instead of `JSON.parse` & `fs.readFileSync`

```
var jsonObj = require('./route1.json');
```

Comment: Yeah, that did it. Thanks a lot! I was so focussed on the whole @-problem that I made a simple mistake.

Comment: Glad to help! It happens sometimes, you think that the problem is X, while it's Y ;)